# Send a serializable class through a Socket

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization

I'm trying to send an ArrayList of Email to a server through a Socket, but when I try to fo this I get a **NotSerializableException: javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty** I read on the forum that I need to implement Serializable into may Email class, which is this:

```
public class Email implements Serializable {

    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public final IntegerProperty IDProperty() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public final Integer getID() {
        return this.IDProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setID(final Integer id) {
        this.IDProperty().set(id);
    }

    private final StringProperty mittente = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty MittenteProperty() {
        return this.mittente;
    }

    public final String getMittente() {
        return this.MittenteProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setMittente(final String mittente) {
        this.MittenteProperty().set(mittente);
    }

    private final StringProperty destinatario = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty DestinatarioProperty() {
        return this.destinatario;
    }

    public final String getDestinatario() {
        return this.DestinatarioProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setDestinatario(final String destinatario) {
        this.DestinatarioProperty().set(destinatario);
    }

    private final StringProperty oggetto = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty OggettoProperty() {
        return this.oggetto;
    }

    public final String getOggetto() {
        return this.OggettoProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setOggetto(final String oggetto) {
        this.OggettoProperty().set(oggetto);
    }

    private final StringProperty testo = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty TestoProperty() {
        return this.testo;
    }

    public final String getTesto() {
        return this.TestoProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setTesto(final String testo) {
        this.TestoProperty().set(testo);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<Date> data = new SimpleObjectProperty<Date>();

    public final ObjectProperty<Date> DataProperty() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public final Date getData() {
        return this.data.get();
    }

    public final void setData(final Date data) {
        this.data.set(data);
    }

    public Email (int id, String mittente, String destinatario, String oggetto, String testo, Date data) {
        setID(id);
        setMittente(mittente);
        setDestinatario(destinatario);
        setOggetto(oggetto);
        setTesto(testo);
        setData(data);
    }
}
```

This is the part where I try to send it:

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
objectOutput.writeObject(arr);
```

But nothing changed. What should I modify?

Comment: Since something in your class isn't serializable by itself (SimpleObjectProperty) and you can't make it, you need to do something more than just add implements Serializable. You need to actually write the serialization and deserialization methods.

Comment: I have to wonder if this could possibly be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in disguise. Are you trying to serialize GUI components (the view portion)? Or are you trying to serialize the underlying data (the model portion) of your program? Also, why use serialization to transmit the data rather then some more friendly format?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm trying to serialize the model portion. This is necessary because if I try to send an Array List of Email I get the error I wrote in the question.

Comment: @Worthless So should I write two methods in my Email list? One for when I want to send a data and one for when I want to receive a data?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `writeObject` and `readObject` methods in your `Email` class because it requires some special handling (it has non-serializable fields).

Also in `readObject` you need some work to initialize `final` fields.

At the end these two methods shold look like this:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(getID());
    out.writeUTF(getMittente());
    out.writeUTF(getDestinatario());
    out.writeUTF(getOggetto());
    out.writeUTF(getTesto());
    out.writeObject(getData());
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException  {

    try {

        Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, new SimpleIntegerProperty());

        field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("mittente");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, new SimpleStringProperty());

        field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("destinatario");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, new SimpleStringProperty());

        field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("oggetto");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, new SimpleStringProperty());

        field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("testo");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, new SimpleStringProperty());

        field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("data");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, new SimpleObjectProperty<Date>());

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }

    setID(in.readInt());
    setMittente(in.readUTF());
    setDestinatario(in.readUTF());
    setOggetto(in.readUTF());
    setTesto(in.readUTF());
    setData((Date)in.readObject());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the write error! Now I'm getting the **java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data** error when compiling. The problem is in the server, at this line: `ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            email = (ArrayList<Email>) inStream.readObject();` How can I write it with the new method I inserted in the Email class?